# Cannot read Excel file with Arabic content using Java

Tags: java, excel

I try to read an Excel file with Arabic content. I made it to read the file but the problem is that the result contains many question marks instead of the correct content.

How I can read the content correctly?

```
File src = new File("C:\\ExcelRW\\CarePost.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
String post_message = sheet1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
System.out.print(post_message);
```

This result: `???? ????? ????`

Answer (score 4):

Use the following Code

`sheet1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getRichStringCellValue();`

instead of:

```
sheet1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue()
```

This applies to UTF-8 encoded characters like Chinese, Arabic or Japanese.